# Extra dupehammer message displaying on non-updated sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, dupehammer

Noticed this on SFF; the question status banner is giving me some [information I already know](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104675/wizarding-court-and-veritaserum):

[image: SFF Dupehammer message]

The bit that says

> Users with the [X] tag badge can single-handedly close [X] questions as duplicated and reopen them as needed.

Seems slightly unnecessary, especially to established users.

As a special bonus bug, there's a bit of CSS weird going on with that gold tag.

This does appear to be network-wide, at least on sites that haven't yet been visited by the Upgrade Fairy; for example, [this post on RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55692/calculating-the-distance-when-shooting-at-a-flying-foe):

[image]

Sites that *have* been upgraded also have this extra message, but it's hidden by default:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this looks a lot like a bug on sites that are using the old CSS (this should only show when you click the badge). Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops!

A fix will be pushed out shortly - thanks for reporting.